# Trying to access Safari developer tools prints "Access not allowed (-1723)"

Tags: applescript, safari, xcode-simulator

I am trying to create a script which lists me all available open simulators to inspect in safari developer tools but when I run the code I get the below error. At the end this script should open the inspector tool for one simulator device. My guess it that in general this is not allowed but I gave the terminal the accessibility rights so yeah I have no idea.

[image]

```
listDevices.applescript:122:168: script error: „"Simulator" of menu "Entwickler" of menu bar 1“ kann nicht gelesen werden. Zugriff nicht erlaubt. (-1723)
```

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        name of every menu item of menu item where its name starts with "Simulator" of menu "Entwickler" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have a *menu item* that starts with **Simulator**; however, using **Experimental** as in **Experimental Features**, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* did retrieve the *names* of the *menu items* on the **Experimental Features** *menu item* of the **Develop** *menu* in **Safari**. (My system is set to **US English**.)

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Safari"
    set menuItemNames to get name of every menu item of menu 1 of ¬
        (first menu item whose name starts with "Experimental") of ¬
        menu 1 of menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1
end tell

return menuItemNames
```

So if you change `"Experimental"` to `"Simulator"` and `"Develop"` to `"Entwickler"` I'd imagine it would work for you.

Comment: That is it, thank you! The Simulator menu item appears if you have a iOS Simulator running to inspect iOS Safari tabs. But is there a way to get the proper translation for "Develop"? When I want to use that script in a library for example I cannot use German here.

Comment: @muuvmuuv, I do not know the answer to that, sorry. It would probably be better if you posted a separate question to address that, pointing back to this as a reference if necessary.